# What is different between compile and provided

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

When I set `<scope>` to `provided`, my application didn't work. When It was compile, however, It works. Can you explain what different between both them.

This is `tileConfig` class for setting path.

```
@Configuration
public class TilesConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions("/WEB-INF/tiles.xml");

        return tilesConfigurer;
}
```

and I added dependencies for Apache Tiles 3 and JSP. Because embedded server (tomcat) in Spring Boot do not support JPS.

Following `pom.xml` is working but when I add `<scope>` as provided in `tomcat-embed-jasper`. It does not work:

```
    <!-- Apache Tiles 3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify the scope as provided, you are saying that you expect JDK or the container to provide the dependency at runtime. This dependency is not present there so it cannot find it.

- **compile** is the default scope - these dependencies are available in all project classpaths
- **provided** - these dependencies are expected to be present int your environment
- **runtime** - not necessary for compilation but needs to be present for runtime
- **test** - required for tests
- **system** - like provided but you need to provide the `jar` file

Answer (score 3):

`provided` means that you expect the container (Tomcat) to provide the dependency. Provided dependencies are used for compilation but are not packaged into your application.

`compile` dependencies are packaged into your applícation.